# Wordpress Redirect on User Edit hook

Tags: php, wordpress

I looked through the Wordpress Hook DB and couldn't find any way to change the page that wordpress redirects to after editing a user... Does anyone know of a hook that will do this, or of another way I could accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter `wp_redirect` only on `user-edit.php`;

```
function my_user_edit_redirect($location)
{
    return admin_url('somewhere/else.php');
}
add_action('load-user-edit.php', create_function('', '
    add_filter("wp_redirect", "my_user_edit_redirect");'));
```

Comment: Hey i wanted to do something same, but thsi function didn't worked for me i put it in functions.php in theme folder. is there anything i missed ?

Comment: @Ayaz which version of WP are you using?